# How to stop different input sources from overriding keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, input-source

My machine has two input sources (English and Hebrew). When I try to use keyboard shortcuts inside apps, it doesn't work in Hebrew but does work in English. How can I stop this override?

For example when using Adobe Acrobat and trying to "save as" with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

My machine: MacBook Pro M1 Pro (14-inch, 2021)
My OS: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: Which Hebrew input source are you using of the 3 provided by Apple?  Do you have the same problem in Apple apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently changing input source to "Hebrew - PC" (and also "QWERTY") fixed it.

@Tom Gewecke, thank you for pointing this option out
[image]